# Pass ViewController's data to HTML file in Highcharts

Tags: ios, ipad, highcharts

I successfully loaded highcharts on iPad with static data. I want to pass dynamic data in from my ViewController to HTML file prepared for loading highcharts's script.

How can I pass the dynamic data? Please guide me for the same.

**PS:** I checked stackoverflow tutorials to pass dynamic data but none of them is talking about passing the data from ViewController to html file.

Comment: hi! any solution on this?? please!

Answer (score 0):

You can get data by ajax, like in the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vw79L/

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({


        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```